# npm audit gets stuck on ENOAUDIT

Tags: node.js, security, npm, audit

npm audit command errors with ENOAUDIT.
with `npm ERR! audit Your configured registry (:url) does not support audit requests.` how do I enable audit command?
npm v6.2.0
node v8.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the private registry is preventing this: either `npm config delete registry` or allow that registry to be audited.